# Confusion about signing android app

Tags: android, android-studio, sign

I am about to publish my first android app. 
For that I have to sign my app. I followed the steps, described here ( http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html ), under the point 
"Signing Your App in Android Studio". 
At the end it said, I received a signed .apk
Under the point "Signing in Release Mode" it also says, I have to edit my gradle file as shown there.

First question: Do I have to do both? So do I have to put my keystore and key I obtained via the other way in the gradle file, or is that just another way?

Second question: Under the point "Automatically Signing Your App" is described another way for signing. Did I understand it right, that when I follow the steps described there, so put in my keystore/key I obtained with the other tool, Android Studio automatically generates the updated .apk everytime I build my project, and otherwise when dont using this tool, I would have to follow the steps of "Signing Your App in Android Studio" everytime again manually?
If so, where would it save the updated .apk, since I cant specify an output directory, and already have my first signed.apk

Third question: Since I did get my signed .apk, I actually have to enter new Api Keys for Google Maps and GCM. But when doing this, and trying to install the app on my phone via USB, I get the exception, that I use a wrong API Key, but when I use my old API Key, I got with the Debug certificate, erverything works. So it seems like Android Studio installs the debug.apk, although I signed the app.

Comment: API keys are totally unrelated to app signing. You don't "get" certificates for Android app signing you create them. Any self-created certificate can be used (in difference to SSL/TLS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Question:** you need only `Signing Your App in Android Studio` part to sign your apk.

**Second Question:** what i do is to keep things as they are, to generate a signed apk i go to: Build > Generate signed apk, for testing i keep the debug mode. to test the signed apk on devise i install it using terminal :`./adb install mysigned.apk`

**Third Question:** to get your Api's working on signed mode you need to generats a new `SHA-1 certificate fingerprint` based on your apk created keys `.jks file` to do so from Android studio terminal:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore /Users/username/Desktop/app_key.jks
```

`/Users/username/Desktop/app_key.jks` is the path to your keys

**Update:**

[image]

terminal example

Comment: In which directory do I have to be, to use the command ./adb install mysigned.apk  ?
When I am in the directory, where the .apk is located, I get an error (that he doesnt recognize the command ".", and when I leave the "./" away, he says, he doesnt recognize the command "adb"

Comment: put this in terminal first `cd /Users/MyUserName/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools` .. replace `MyUserName` by yours

Comment: Ok, seems to work, just that it says it is an invalid.apk?

Comment: now you are in a different folder.. in `platform-tools` not in the one with the Apk.. use: `./adb install /Users/Username/Desktop/yourapk.apk`.. i have the apk in the desktop.. i updated my answer with a picture.

Comment: I found a way, which ist at least for me working better, maybe it helps you or another people too:
Going on the left down corner of Android Studio, click on that little box, click build types, change everything from debugg to release, follow the instructions from the google site for signing automatically, and than you can normally install your newest signed apk with the run button, and dont have to think of the debug version anymore

Comment: thank you Luca, i can recommend your way after publishing your App to play store for the first time.. i think build time is slower plus some API's for testing you need the debug version (Strip for example)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a awnser on your second question.
If you have build your app to an APK on time you can just click on build APK.
(Edit the version in Gradle first)
Thennit just makes a updated ApK for you.